# Bootstrap modal not showing on top of SVG

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to have a bootstrap modal show when a button is clicked. The page is using an SVG since it needs to have visual paths/nodes. When the button is clicked the modal does not show up. When using the page inside an iframe, however, the modal will show up.

Here is the code for the page in question:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mb.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NEditor.css" />
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato"
        rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="Utilities.js"></script>
    <script src="NodeClasses.js"></script>
    <script src="NodeMethods.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Lato";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div
        class="btn-group"
        role="group"
        aria-label="Basic example"
        style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 5px;"
    >
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            id="CommandBtn"
            style="background-color: #6c757d;"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#addCommand"
        >
            Add Command
        </button>
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            id="ResponseBtn"
            style="background-color: #6c757d;"
        >
            Add Response
        </button>
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            id="SaveBtn"
            style="background-color: #6c757d;"
        >
            Save Flow
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 15px;">
        <svg id="connsvg"></svg>


    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="addCommand">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">New Command</h4>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        class="close"
                        data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    >
                        ×
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1"
                            >Command name</label
                        >
                        <input class="form-control" id="commandName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a
                        href="#"
                        data-dismiss="modal"
                        class="btn btn-secondary"
                        >Close</a
                    >
                    <a
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        style="color: white;"
                        id="addCommandBtn"
                        data-dismiss="modal"
                        >Add</a
                    >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
        src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
</body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        loadNodesFromFile();
        loadNode();
        /* var n4 = new NEditor.Node("Compile Results");
        var n4i1 = n4.addInput("Input A");
        var n4i2 = n4.addInput("Input B");
        n4.setPosition(700, 180);

        var n3 = new NEditor.Node("Some Process");
        var n3i1 = n3.addInput("Input");
        var n3o1 = n3.addOutput("Output");
        n3.setPosition(300, 50);
        n3.setWidth(200);

        n3o1.connectTo(n4i2);

        var n2 = new NEditor.Node("Some Other Process");
        var n2i1 = n2.addInput("Input");
        var n2o1 = n2.addOutput("Output");
        n2.setPosition(300, 300);
        n2.setWidth(200);

        n2o1.connectTo(n4i1);

        var n1 = new NEditor.Node('"Help" command');
        var n1o1 = n1.addOutput("Response");
        n1.setPosition(50, 200);

        n1o1.connectTo(n2i1);
        n1o1.connectTo(n3i1); */
    });

    document.body.style.width = "2000px";
    document.body.style.height = "1000px";

    // #####################
    // SETUP UI
    // #####################
    //var commandButton = document.getElementById("CommandBtn");
    var saveButton = document.getElementById("SaveBtn");

    // Create new command node
    //commandButton.addEventListener("click", function() {});

    // Save the current flow state
    saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        saveFlowState();
        location.href = "./index.html";
    });
</script>
```

The button with id CommandBtn is the one I am trying to use.

Comment: When it is configured to open in the page instead of through an `iframe` do you have any console errors? (Hit F12 to view these)

Comment: @EGC no I do not get any errors. Also worth noting that this is in an Electron application, but that doesn't seem relevant for this issue.

Comment: Have you attempted to force the `z-index` of the modal to be in front of all other elements?

Comment: @EGC yep, that was the first thing I tried. No luck there

Comment: Can you verify 100% that the modal isn't appearing when it is configured to show on the `page`? I.e. in DevTools go through the HTML and 100% check it's not showing. My thoughts are that the iframe is capturing / forcing the modal position, and when it is rendering onto the page, it is displaying out of view or something random like that.

Comment: @EGC thanks for the help... turns out for some reason using the form `window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");` to import jQuery instead of using a script with source from cloudflare has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```